# C# networking TcpClient

Tags: c#, networking, tcpclient

Can someone tell me why "Went Through?" gets printed only when argument to Thread.Sleep is < 110?

Update <7.X.2011 5PM ET>: I think what is happening is that the server end is being saturated with client Write(a)'s which then somehow impacts the ability to send data before the connection is closed.  Maybe network read buffer is being filled up?

Whenever the iteration count gets above 165xx, the "Went Through?" is not sent, anytime iteration count is <165xx, the string gets sent.  This number is reached at Sleep of 107 and onward.  Sleep value of 107 sends the string sometimes, depending on other (OS) threads running in the background.

The iteration value never gets above 165xx, even when Sleep is set to a large value (say 2sec), which leads me to believe the network buffer is full.

```
    static void fClient()
    {
        int iterations = 0;
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient("localhost", 22320);

        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(client.GetStream());
        BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(client.GetStream());
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                if (client.Available > 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(br.ReadString());
                }
                else
                {
                    bw.Write("a");
                    iterations++;
                }
            }
            catch (IOException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("EXCEPTION");
                //exception always reads: Unable to write....
                // (thrown by bw.Write("a"))
                // show iterations count
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TcpListener server = new TcpListener(22320);
        server.Start();

        new Thread(fClient).Start();
        Thread.Sleep(200);

        TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();

        BinaryWriter binWrite = new BinaryWriter(client.GetStream());
        binWrite.Write("Went Through?");
        binWrite.Flush();
        client.Close();
    }
```

Comment: I'm seeing it however long the sleep is... what are you seeing when you don't see the "Went through?" text? It would really help if you didn't throw away the potentially helpful exception... print it out instead.

Comment: I see "EXCEPTION", it's an IOException (thrown by 'bw.Write("a")), result of broken TCP/IP connection, the reason I don't print it is I've been working with various version of this code for past few hrs and so I know what it is and is of no interest :)

Comment: Ideally the output should be: Went Through?, EXCEPTION, finished execution.  But I only get EXCEPTION.

Comment: If I remove the "client.Available > 0" check, then I get "Went Through?" printed, as it should be.

Comment: This whole exercise is me testing the client.Available property, at least it started out that way, because it doesn't behave like I expected it to.

Comment: I've started writing an answer a few times now (I *can* provoke it with a 5 second sleep now) but I'd really be guessing. Have you tried using something like Wireshark to see what's going on at the network level?

Comment: Nope, maybe I will if no one can come up with an answer.

Comment: Also, If I add Thread.Sleep(anyVal) just before client.Close(), the result is unchanged, other than "EXCEPTION" being printed later.

Comment: I'm starting to think that client.Available is badly implemented or I need to look over the TCP/IP protocol specification.

Comment: Ok, Wireshark results. Wireshark runs on the comp with the server, client runs on a laptop.  The "a"s from the client always appear in Wireshark log, I managed to get "Went Through?" once on the client, that was the very first time I run the client on the laptop.  After that, "Went Through?" no longer appears on the client.  For "Went Through?" to appear on the client I have to place Thread.Sleep(anyVal [even 1 works]) right before client.Close() in the server code.  When done, I always get a TCP/IP packet with many "a"s followed by "Went Through?" and...

Comment: ...then any additional "a" packets depending on sleep value.  If the client does not print "Went Through?", it seems to be because it never got sent.

Comment: If adding Sleep before Close passes the string through, does that mean that without the Sleep the network stack (?) thread that would send the string does not get to run before Close is called?

Comment: But, if I remove if (client.Available > 0) check from the client, then I don't need to add sleep before close and the client always displays "Went Through?". What's up with this Available property!? Or am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: I think we might need a TCP/IP expert here.

Answer (score 0):

I also think the code is straightforward:) But this one doesn't use Sleep to synchronize threads.

```
static Semaphore Go = new Semaphore(0, 1);

static void Server()
{
    TcpListener server = new TcpListener(22320);
    server.Start();
    Go.Release();

    while (true)
    {
        TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
        new Thread((x) => ServerTask(x)).Start(client);
    }
}

static void ServerTask(object clnObj)
{
    TcpClient client = clnObj as TcpClient;

    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(client.GetStream());
    BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(client.GetStream());

    string s = "FromServer: " + br.ReadString();
    bw.Write(s);

    client.Close();
}

static void Client(int i)
{

    TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
    client.Connect("localhost", 22320);

    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(client.GetStream());
    BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(client.GetStream());

    bw.Write(i.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(br.ReadString());

    client.Close();

}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Thread t = new Thread(() => Server());
    t.IsBackground = true;
    t.Start();
    Go.WaitOne();

    Console.WriteLine("Server Started....");
    Parallel.For(0, 21, (i) => Client(i));
    Console.WriteLine("Clients Processed");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Well, the issue is not to get a particular thing done.  The issue is why something that should be working, one would think, is not.  In an application I'm working on I rely on client.Available a lot and in testing the app it appears that it may be a wrong approach, so I went out to test this property and became even more confused :)

Comment: Well, never use Sleep to sync. threads since you can never now for sure when it will be executed, which one will be executed first etc.

Comment: I use sleep mainly to yield or prevent spinning.

Answer (score 0):

I think I finally figured this out.

Two endpoints A and B talking to each other: A <-> B

When A sends a message to B and then closes its TcpClient object, I assumed that the TcpClient.Available property on B will still list that last message from A as received and then BinaryReader.ReadString() would be able to retrieve that message, even though the TCP/IP connection was broken by A.

I observed, that that was not always the case and now I think I understand why.

After A closes connection, if B only does reads from network, then it will be able to grab that last message from A and Available property will reflect that message's presence.  But if B does a write to the network, then that write will instantly detect a broken connection and fail any subsequent reads/writes, even if Available property returns >0.

So in fact I did understand Available property correctly, but learned today that there are exceptions, when the property will not behave as expected.

If I'm wrong, please correct me.  Now onto changing my app.

Comment: For completeness sake I'll add, that it seems this whole issue of not being able to access the read network buffer is due to an RST TCP/IP packet being sent, which instantly invalidates sockets on both ends of the connection.